# Distinct users in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have the following problem: 
In my Cassandra database I have several messages sent by several users.
My messages table has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
  recipient bigint,
  sender bigint,
  created_at text,
  content text,
  PRIMARY KEY((recipient, sender),created_at)
);
```

I need to count the number of messages sent by a user in a day. For example, between the date 2017-01-01 and 2017-01-05

```
sender | created_at
  1       2017-01-01
  1       2017-01-01
  2       2017-01-01
  3       2017-01-02  
  3       2017-01-02
  4       2017-01-03
  4       2017-01-04
  5       2017-01-04
```

I would have the result

```
2017-01-01 = 2
2017-01-02 = 1
2017-01-03 = 1  
2017-01-04 = 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, you cannot do that with your table structure because your partition key contains the `recipient`. To be told, you should not count at all, because [counting keys in cassandra](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/counting-keys-in-cassandra) is hard.

However, if you insist on counting these keys, I suggest you two approaches:

---

### Create a new counter table

```
CREATE TABLE counters_by_user (
    sender bigint,
    ts timestamp,
    messages counter,
    PRIMARY KEY (sender, ts)
)
```

This table will allow you to directly fetch the value you are looking for. It allows you to select the appropriate "granularity" of the counters, that is if you want a day-by-day counter simply store the timestamp in the `ts` field in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format. If you want hourly-based counting, store it in `yyyy-mm-dd HH:00` format, etc... You'll need the exact `sender` only to fetch the results, and can range query by specifying the `ts` component of the primary key. Have a look at the [Counters](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_counter_t.html) page documentation on how to use them, and beware that the main drawback of this approach is that Cassandra can over/under count, so watch your steps if you need to be pedantic on counting.

---

### Create a new message table, aka denormalize your data

```
CREATE TABLE messages_by_sender (
    sender bigint,
    created_at timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY (sender, created_at)
);
```

Every time you insert a row in the `messages` table you'll insert a row here, and when you need to count the messages sent you simply run a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages_by_sender WHERE sender=?` to count them all, or `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages_by_sender WHERE sender=? AND created_at > ? AND created_at < ?;` to specify a range. If you have a lot of messages per `sender`, however this will lead to inefficiency, since counting keys in Cassandra requires a partition scan.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works perfectly for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, cassandra doesn't allow do SQL-like aggregations. You either need to pre-compute & keep into another database OR do the counting as the results are being scanned/queried.

Another option it to integrate cassandra with hadoop & do some map-reduce, but that seems like an overkill for what you're trying here.